# Getting error The maximum clients per tenant limit has been exceeded from messagehub

Tags: message-hub

We are currently using messagehub for our development.  We have the following instance of MessageHub configured:

However, when we try to launch our application, we are getting the error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 NetworkError: CONNECTION ERROR (amqp:not-allowed) The maximum clients per tenant limit has been exceeded.
at Error (native)
at waitForStart (C:\Clients\Merck\Dev\MSD 
Dashboard\node_modules\mqlight\mqlight.js:1580:36)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Clients\Merck\Dev\MSD    
Dashboard\node_modules\mqlight\mqlight.js:1582:30)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Any idea, what is causing this?  We are not able to launch any modules of the application that use this functionality.

Mihir

Comment: "the following instance of MessageHub" seems to be missing. Please edit the post to show all needed information.

Answer (score 3):

The MQ Light API interface to the Message Hub service limits the number of simultaniously connected clients to 25 (see the [Maximum limits](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub083) section of the documentation).

So the cause could be, simply, that you have scaled your application to have more than 25 instances running at any given time.

Another possibility is that your application is *leaking* instances of the MQ Light client. For example, the following code will try and create 26 instances of the client (25 will succeed and 1 will fail):

```js
var mqlight = require('mqlight');
var opts = {
  service: "https://mqlight-lookup-url-here",
  user: "secret",
  password: "secret"
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 26; ++i) {
  client = mqlight.createClient(opts);
  var printStarted = function(count) {
    return function() {console.log('Client ' + count + ' started');};
  }
  var printError = function(count) {
    return function(error) {
      console.log('Client ' + count + ' failed to start due to ' + error);
    };
  };
  client.on('started', printStarted(i));
  client.on('error', printError(i));
}
```

However, because each instance of the client goes out of scope as soon as it is created - it still remains connected and counts towards the maximum number of connected clients for its instance of the Message Hub service - until the Node.js process running this code ends.

If you suspect your application may be "leaking" MQ Light clients you can use `netstat` to list all the connections to the MQ Light service.

For example, on Windows:

```
netstat -o | find ":5671" | find "ESTABLISHED"
```

or on Linux:

```
netstat -p --numeric-ports | grep ':5671.*ESTABLISHED'
```

If your application *is* leaking MQ Light clients then the straightforward fix is to ensure that you always call [client.stop([callback])](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqlight#mqlightclientstopcallback) on each instance of the client before it goes out of scope. This will cause the client to disconnect from the Message Hub service, and no longer be counted against the number of simultaneously connected clients.